# Setting 100% width of view-port in bootstrap 4.5

Tags: bootstrap-4

i'm trying to get a 100% width using `class='row'` in a container

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="container"><!-- this is main container holding overall contents dont want to remove it -->
    <div class='row w-100 bg-dark' id='heading'>
      <h2>some headings</h2>
    </div>
    <article></article>
    <aside></aside>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

the row with `id='heading'` is not expanding to 100% width because its in a container class, i used the layout utility w-100 but its not working.

**how can i force this div to expand to 100% but remains in the container?**

Comment: yup container is the issue, use `container-fluid` instead, also plop `no-gutters` on `row` if you dont want spacing between cols, at least one col should be a child of `row` else your have -15px which will cause horiz scroll bar bug

Comment: It'll affect on the whole layout! i just wanted to make `#heading` to be 100% not the other area.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, split the two and have header in a `container-fluid`

```
<article>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters" id="heading">
      <div class="col">
        <h2>some headings</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <article></article>
    <aside></aside>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</article>
```

`article` is just a wrap so you can see.

---

Edit:

Using absolute positioning to yank out the header from the container, not ideal as may cause other issues, but its an option

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

article {
  margin-top: 65px
}

#heading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id='heading'>
    <h2>some headings</h2>
  </div>
  <article>Lorum ipsum</article>
  <aside>Lorum ipsum</aside>
  <footer>Lorum ipsum</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: dear lawrence, the problem is i can not move the container class, it'll be there by any means so is there any way i can override the parent width and achieve the 100%?

Comment: nothing should be set in stone especially a template, it would be worth moving/refactoring it. (been there) but you might be able to use one of absolute, fixed or sticky positioning on #header but that comes with other issues like making it look like relative.

Comment: Actually i'm just doing the UI part and it came hard coded. so i guess i have to refactor it

Comment: I added position: absolute; as an example, but is not ideal. Hope it helps

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back to you. Thanks Lawrence.